# Template Page - Listar dados e enviar para outro template

Tags: php, wordpress

Amigos,

Estou listando dados de produtos vindo de uma tabela criada na estrutura do wp. Criei uma página "produtos.php" template onde listo assim:

```
produto 1
produto 2
produto 3
...
```

Cada produto desse terá um link que apontará para outra página com item do produto "produtos-item.php"

É possível fazer isso no WP com templates?

```
<a url="???">produto 1</a>
```

Terei que apontar para outra página template (produtos-item.php)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode percorrer a lista de produtos, pegando os ids dos mesmos e usando eles para compor a URL do `produtos-item.php`

```
<a url="produtos-item.php?id=$id">produto 1</a>
```

Vai você recuperar na página produtos-item.php usando o `$_GET['id']`

Comment: Fiz isso, funcionou legal, obrigado, porém tô pensando aqui na url amigável. Como farei pra colocar essas urls amigáveis. Acho que vou ter que criar um slug para cada produto.

Comment: Exato, você salva um slug e depois usa .htaccess para remover o id, mas recomendo ao invés de remover deixar no padrão site.com/1/tv-lcd

Comment: pode suar site.com.br/produto/1/produto-a

Comment: vou tentar fazer, obrigado amigo.

Comment: o 1 seria o id? com o slug acho que não precisaria desse id.

Comment: vai dar um trabalhinho essa gambiarra, o certo seria fazer um plugin. rs

Comment: Não precisa, mas o certo, ao meu ver e sempre pegar dados do produto por ID e so colocar o slug para o SEO, pois caso mude o slug para outra coisa, o ID não muda e você não perde a referencia para a página. nunca terá problema de SEO. se não usar o ID você da erro 404 sempre que mudar o slug de um produto e sabemos que isso muda sempre (pelo menos meus clientes)

Comment: Vdd amigo. Valeu.

Comment: Surgiu outro obstaculo aqui. além da url tem a questão do title, description, canonical, etc... na página de item do produto. Quero ver como vou fazer isso, já que estou querendo algo dinâmico em uma page que é estática.